# How to remove set of fields in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with two fields FName and LName. I have bind some data into form. In HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="col-lg-12 row">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let name of names; index as i">
    <div class="col-lg-12 row">
      <div class="form-field-cont col-lg-4">
        <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
          <mat-label>F_Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" value="{{name.fname}}" formControlName="fname">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="form-field-cont col-lg-4">
        <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
          <mat-label>L_Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" value="{{name.lname}}" formControlName="lname">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mt-3">
        <ng-container>
          <i class="material-icons cursor-pointer" matTooltip="Remove" (click)="removeExistingNode(i)" style="color:red;">delete</i> 
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

In ts:

```
  names: any = [{ fname: "ABC", lname: "PQR" }, { fname: "XYZ", lname: "RST" }];
  Form: FormGroup;
  formBuilderObj: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormBuilderObj();
    this.createForm();
  }

  createFormBuilderObj() {
    this.formBuilderObj = {
      fname: [{ value: "", disabled: true }],
      lname: [{ value: "", disabled: true }]
    };
  }

  createForm() {
    this.Form = this.formBuilder.group(this.formBuilderObj);
    console.log("this.form", this.Form.value);
  }

  removeExistingNode(index) {}
```

I am able to render form fields. Now I want to remove some records when I click on delete button. Please help to achieve this. I was try to use `FormArray` but getting errors. Thanks in advance.
I have created **stackblitz** here is the link: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eshfqa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: there're many many errors in your code. Please, take a look e.g. this link about FormArrays:https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the form array and achieve this.
[updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-abgjyy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)